# Immediately Allocate All RAM to Virtual Machine at Power-On

Tags: memory, performance, vmware-fusion

(I didn't know whether post this question on superuser or serverfault.  The original post with all of the background info is on https://serverfault.com/q/981374/134315.  I hope it is okay to include the question here too.)

---

I would like to force VMWare (Fusion) to pre-allocate all of the RAM assigned to a specific virtual machine as soon as that VM is powered on.  Does anyone know how to do that?

(I assume I will have to manually add a setting to the VM's `.vmx` file.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Immediately Allocate All RAM to Virtual Machine at Power-On](https://superuser.com/questions/1477440/immediately-allocate-all-ram-to-virtual-machine-at-power-on)

Answer (score 1):

This is a print of the **edit settings** of a VM on ESXi:

[image]

I assume Horizon will provide the same options to reserve the memory on the resources tab.

Once the **Reserve all guest memory (All locked)** is checked the following lines are added to the .vmx file:

```
sched.mem.min = "2048"  
sched.mem.pin = "TRUE"
```

Comment: This is a different UI than I have on Fusion.  It looks like the `[x] Reserve all guest memory` option is what I need.  Can you tell which setting this writes to the `.vmx` file for the virtual machine?

Comment: @JamesL., I edited the answer to add the code generated on the .vmx.

Comment: Thank you!  I edited the `.vmx` and added those values.  The VM did not immediately allocate the RAM, but continued to behave as before.  Thanks for your help.  I think these, with a few other settings that I've been playing with might be what I need.  I'll post back if I find something that works...

Comment: Note that the `sched.mem.min` value ("Reservation" in the ESXi UI) needs to exactly match the `memSize` value ("Memory" or "RAM" in the ESXi UI depending on the ESXi version). So if you ever change `memSize` without the ESXi UI, be sure to also change `sched.mem.min`.